# Robot Framework: Take screenshot if any keyword fails

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, robotframework, ui-automation

In the robot framework, I need to take a screenshot of the page when any keyword is failed. Currently, I am using code like:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary    run_on_failure=Capture Page Screenshot

Suite Setup      Open Browser

Suite Teardown   Close Browsers  


*** Variables ***
${url}     
${browser}        chrome

*** Test Cases ***
TC01
     Keyword 1
     Keyword 2
     Keyword 3
TC02
     Keyword 4
     Keyword 5
```

However, along with failed cases, it takes screenshots even if the keyword succeeds. As a result, there is an influx of screenshots and it is hard to find which one is for the failed case.

Is there any way to take a screenshot only if the keyword fails?

Comment: Most keywords will not create a screenshot when they pass. Can you provide an actual example of a keyword that takes a screenshot when it passes?

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature in Selenium2Library.
Try reading more about it here's the documentation link->https://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html
Download that using pip command!

Library    Selenium2Library  timeout=10   implicit_wait=1.5   run_on_failure=Capture Page Screenshot

Let me know if it helps!

Comment: You basically just rewrote what the OP included in their question. Please be a bit more specific in your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try such code:

```
${success} =  Run Keyword And Return Status  YourKeyword
Run Keyword If  not ${success}  Capture Page Screenshot
```